# xlsx file is not recognized by java after being exported in JAR

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, xlsx

I have made a javaFX application with Maven which reads a xlsx file, and copy its content in an H2 database. When I run the main or app class, everythings works, however when I create an artifact, build it and then run the JAR, I have this error message :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream or you haven't provide the poi-ooxml*.jar in the classpath/modulepath - FileMagic: OOXML, having providers: [org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbookFactory@6da69075]
    at com.example.demo.ExportInterneController$1.handle(ExportInterneController.java:100)
    at com.example.demo.ExportInterneController$1.handle(ExportInterneController.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8923)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3894)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream or you haven't provide the poi-ooxml*.jar in the classpath/modulepath - FileMagic: OOXML, having providers: [org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbookFactory@6da69075]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:334)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
    at com.example.demo.Export.export(Export.java:27)
    at com.example.demo.ExportInterneController$1.handle(ExportInterneController.java:96)
    ... 46 more
```

Here are the line that cause the error :

```
        String fileName = Stockage.filePlantesURL;             //This line is Export.java:27
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        int nombrePages = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
```

and the String used is "C:\Users\calon\Downloads\Base de données 2023(3).xlsx".
When I open the JAR with 7-ZIP, i find this, so I don't think the error comes from the "you haven't provide the poi-ooxml*.jar" part of the error.
[image: View of the content of the poi inside the JAR, where we can see the ooxml folder]

Also, here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>google-api-services-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.demo.App</mainClass>
                    <launcher>app</launcher>
                    <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                    <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                    <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                    <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                    <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Do you have an idea of what I have done wrong?

Comment: Well, your exception message says "... or you haven't provide the poi-ooxml*.jar in the classpath/modulepath". So, as a first step, I suggest checking your classpath / modulepath.

Comment: Here is my module-info (I forgot to put it here): "module com.example.demo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires org.json;
    requires org.apache.poi.poi;
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires com.h2database;
    opens com.example.demo to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.demo;
}" Since it has "    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;", the poi.ooxml jar is added to the module path?

Comment: A `require` in a `module-info` does not necessarily mean the required modules are available at *runtime*. Use `System.out.println(System.getProperty("jdk.module.path"))` to print and check your *runtime* module path.

Comment: When I add the System.out.println(System.getProperty("jdk.module.path")),  it writes "null" if it comes from the artifact, but if i don't export it, I have differents jars, with \poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.3.jar in it

Comment: If there is no module path, I guess you are not running your application as a modular application. In that case, check the runtime classpath, i.e. `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` or run your application as a modular application.

Comment: More likely there is a problem with the file name.

Comment: Okay, I don't know why but changing the Workbook into an XSSFWorkbook solved the problem. I don't understand why it was working before the export.